# Creating date string with inclusion of time zone

Tags: go

I tried a couple of ways to generate `2021-08-06T16:00:00+0200` string from time.Now(), where trailing +0200 indicates the timezone (in this example CET time zone), including the following method, but it was not attaching the time difference correctly.

```
func createDateString(time time.Time) string {
if time.IsZero() {
    return ""
}
return time.UTC().Format("2006-01-02T15:04:05Z")
```

}

How can I efficiently generate `2021-08-06T16:00:00+0200` -like string from current time, without obtaining time zone separately and then concatenating it.

Comment: https://pkg.go.dev/time#Time.Format

Comment: You must use `-0700` in the format string for the zone offset.

Comment: You're getting `Z` as the time zone because you're calling `UTC`, which gives you zulu (UTC) time. If you want local time, use `time.Now()`.

Comment: I except to receive time to receive as input of the function, not necessarily time.Now(). I have already tested with time.Now.

Comment: https://play.golang.org/p/VOy8hTHPp-S -- as pointed out by icza you should use `-0700` instead of `Z`, and as pointed out by Adrian you should drop the `.UTC()` call.

Comment: Use `time.RFC3339`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based on the suggestion of mkopriva using `-700` instead of `Z` and removing `.UTC()`:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "time"
)

func main() {
    loc := time.FixedZone("CET", 2*60*60)
    now := time.Now().In(loc)
    fmt.Println(createDateString(now))
}

func createDateString(time time.Time) string {
    if time.IsZero() {
        return ""
    }
    return time.Format("2006-01-02T15:04:05-0700")
}
```

Output:

```
2009-11-11T01:00:00+0200
```